# How to send data from an Android application to a server?

Tags: android, sockets, long-polling, chess, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developping an online Chess game in Android. The first player uses the app and the second a webpage in html.

What i want to do is to send the text with the information of every move each player makes in his turns. All the processing and validation parts of the game will be done in the Android application. The second player just receives the text, parses it into html code and then send a very similar text to the application in order to receive the authorisation of the move.

I'm really trying to spend the least possible of internet resources.

I've been searching what's my best option in order to send the messages with Android, but since I'm not very experienced with it, I don't know what to do.

I found these possibilities for sending the messages:

- [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)
- Android ServerSockets and Sockets
- [Making Push technology, like long-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

I have never used any of those technologies, but I would like to know which one could be the best for starting to make a deeper research of.

As you can see a chess game doesn't need a great amount of messaging since I have to send and receive a single message per move and per the authorisation of it by the chess engine in the Android application.

If you know a better solution or links with an example of the technology I should use, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your case it's just matter if the the Android player will need to be with the app running (real time play) or there will be the option to send the play, play turn off the app, and see the next move in a few hours?

If it's a real time just open the connection and use polling or sockets to keep the game running.

If it won't be a real time game, GCM is probably your best approach.

But remind that both options will mean you'll need your own web-server running stuff.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, i didn't thought about the game being real time or not. I think I'm going with sockets since GCM needs a google account in the client device before Android 4.04

Comment: `google account in the client device before Android 4.04`, I'm not sure what you're talking about here as per the following link GCM works with android 2.2 and up. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html#requirements

Comment: Yes, it can be used in all devices after Android 2.2, but all previous devices before Android 4.0.4 need to have a Google account linked to the device, 
(http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html Look at the last point of the introduction)

Comment: but will you releasing the app outside of the google play? If the answer is 'no', it doesn't matter, because for a user to enter Google Play and download your app he/she needs first to have an account.

Comment: Actually, I am. It will be an application for a specific device. Users won't have the option of linking an account to the device themselves. That's why is a limitation for me, but thank you anyway, your response helped me out.